# Problems installing gcc for cross compiling for ARM

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, arm

Problems installing gcc for cross compiling for ARM

I've been trying to install the gcc-arm-linux-fnueabi package, and I've done it a few times by a few different methods but I always seem to be missing the c++ folder in the includes directory.

To install, I used:

sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf

and after the installation completes, I have the arm-linux-gnueabi and arm-linux-gnueabihf folders in my /usr directory. When I go into the /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include folder though, there's no c++ folder as I expect there to be, so headers such as iostream, etc. are missing. Same goes for within the arm-linux-gnueabihf directory.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? Did I miss something, perhaps? I'm fairly new to cross compiling but all the documentation I've studied indicates that there should be a c++ folder among the includes, and without it, my attempts to compile even simple test codes fail, since even the iostream header is not available.

My machine: 32 &64 bit intel i5 processor, on a Asus  running Ubuntu 14.10

Target devices: Beaglebone ( black)

Comment: [According to Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=arm-linux-gnueabihf&searchon=names&suite=utopic&section=all), it's presumably installed GCC exactly as requested; G++ is in a separate package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use eclipse and the set path to /usr/bin and run a program see if it gives any error

Comment: I have a project in pure c source code and their headers for beaglebone black. i can cross compile it in visual studio 2010 but I cant cross compile it in eclipse cdt .can any one help me? (i set the cross compiler toolchain)

Comment: May I suggest you install the 4.7 version of arm-linux-gnueabihf, as it is more stable and if you have c code then g++ is not needed, in eclipse it may show an warning but not eny error...have a look at derek molloy's video on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9yFyWsyyGk